# browser doesnt show response until closing its stream

Tags: java, sockets, http, https, stream

I'm working on a simple webserver app with Java. Everything is OK but when http response or an html document sends to browser such as Firefox or chrome browser doesn't show anything until the output stream or socket being closed. Is there any way to force browser to show results without closing streams? 
Or is there any problem in my codes?

Note that http response header and its body is correct(content-lenght) but browser still loading and never show anything.

```
public void run()
{
    byte [] recbuf = new byte[16384]; //buffer 16KB
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        while(CatServerSocket.isConnected())
        {
            i = CatServerSocket.getInputStream().read(recbuf,0,16384); //here 
            if(i<0)break;
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(recbuf,0,i);
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
            //if socket or output stream closed here, browser shows results
            System.out.println("INFO: " + i + " bytes recieved from CatServer!");
            System.out.println((new String(recbuf,0,i)));
        }
        System.out.println("ERROR: Connection to CatServer lost!");
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java at any place, whenever you read from any stream. You should close that stream. Then only you will be able to get the data from byte array you have created. And here in this code it is nothing wrong to close that stream.